# Got error object required when connecting WMI

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I want to create an Excel log file to record the hostname, IP, status of `ping` and the status of a WMI connection. When I try to run the script I've got an error "object required", but when I check the code I couldn't find where I should change the code.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InputFile = Fso.OpenTextFile("file.txt", 1)
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
intRow = 2

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hostname"
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "IP"
objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Ping"
objExcel.Cells(1, 4).Value = "WMI"

Do While Not (InputFile.atEndOfStream)
  hostname = InputFile.ReadLine

  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & hostname, 0, True)

  objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = hostname

  Select Case Ping
    Case 0 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = "On Line"
    Case 1 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = "Off Line"
    Case 2 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = "N/A"
  End Select

  Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & hostname & "\root\cimv2")
  Set IPconfig = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")

  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = "Pass"
    For Each IP In IPconfig
      If Not IsNull(IP.IPAddress) Then
        For i = LBound(IP.IPAddress) To UBound(IP.IPAddress)
          objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = IP.IPAddress(i)
        Next
      Else
        objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "N/A"
      End If
    Next
  Else
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = Err.Description
  End If

  intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

objExcel.Range("A1:B1:C1:D1").Select
objExcel.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
objExcel.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 11
objExcel.Selection.Font.Bold = True
objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

InputFile.Close
On Error Goto 0

Set objExcel = Nothing
Set Fso      = Nothing
Set InputFile = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
Set Ping = Nothing
Set IPconfig = Nothing

MsgBox "Done Analyse"
objExcel.Quit
Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & hostname, 0, True)
```

`WshShell` returns an integer not an object. Set is ONLY user for objects. So just delete `set` word.

Wmi can do it's own pinging. Here's the command line version but you can plug it in to the WMI statement you are using for NetworkAdaptor.

```
wmic /append:"textfile.txt" path win32_pingstatus where "address='127.0.0.1' and responsetime > 100" get responsetime,timestamprecord
```

For help that is same as vbscript type `wmic path win32_pingstatus get /?`

Comment: hi noodles thanks for the advice :-) now i understand why the error keep shown up :-) thank for the explanation. i really appreciate it thanks again

Comment: hi noodles i want to ask more how to connect the other pc remotely? because i had the error that told the server machine is unavailable

Comment: If hostname is correct then it's unavailable. Hostname do NOT have preceding backslashes, so `computername` not `\\computername`

Comment: im sorry noodles to ask u more i'll try remove backslashes and the error come out object required to all machine why it comes like that

Comment: then ive got this error
error null: 8004100E
what ive understand is this error means the invalid namespace but ive checked that namespace is correct